# PHP navigating to page on login dependent on user role

Tags: php

I'm trying to direct users to specific pages once they have logged in, dependent on their role. I have the following code which logs in a user and directs them to the homepage, but doesn't consider their role:

```
public function login($context, $local)
{
    if ($context->hasuser())
    { # already logged in
    $local->message('message', 'Please log out before trying to login');
    }
    else
    {
    if (($lg = $context->postpar('login', '')) !== '')
    {
        $page = $context->postpar('page', '');
        $pw = $context->postpar('password', '');
        if ($pw !== '')
        {
        $user = $this->eorl($lg);
        if (is_object($user) && $user->pwok($pw) && $user->confirm)
        {
            if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
            { # no session started yet
            session_start();
            }
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            $context->divert($page === '' ? '/' : $page); # success - divert to home page
        }
        }
        $local->message('message', 'Please try again.');
    }
            else
            {
                $page = $context->getpar('page', '');
            }
            $local->addval('page', $page);
    }
    return 'login.twig';
}
```

I also have a function which checks if the user is a candidate:

```
    public function hascandidate()
    {
        return $this->hasuser() && $this->luser->iscandidate();
    }
```

I'm trying to get the system to direct the user to a page '/applyjob' if they are a candidate. Would anyone be able to help?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are trying to load the page (are you using a framework?)

php's header() function may be what you are looking for.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what hascandidate() returns and if your using any frameworks my best guess would be try adding this

`if (hascandidate() == true) { $context->divert('/applyjob'); }`

Right above this:

`$context->divert($page === '' ? '/' : $page);`